# Can introjs validate forms?

Tags: intro.js

I noticed that introjs can [move from page to page](http://introjs.com/example/multi-page/index.html). But I have [a login page](http://app.mapotempo.com) on the way :

[image]

So I must fill the form, then click the connexion button.

**Can introjs validate forms ?**

Asked an other way : **After filling up some input fields while demoing the apps, can introjs click on a button ?**

Answer (score 0):

No, the point of using Intro.js is not to validate your forms BUT you can setup your steps, use the onchange event to figure out the step number and then do you what inside the onchange function.

Of course, you can click on a button like `$('#btn').click();` in the body of callback function. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be possible if you use Intro.js for that case. However, in my opinion, Intro.js is used basically for product tour.

If you want to use it for validation, you can insert a method when click the connexion button. If you use react/vue/JQuery, you can redirect it in the method section and add conditional validation there. If its true the Intro.js starts.